Exception when handling std::shared_ptr and using std::dynamic_pointer_cast
I currently have this problem with a std::shared_ptr. Or at least, I think the problem is there.
I have an app whose input data are passed through an interface from the calling program to the app itself. Among the input data passed through the interface there's also a raw pointer to a class (base_class). Such class also have many derived classes and the pointer can be to one of the derived classes and I need to understand which one.
In order to understand which of the derived classes (from base_class) the passed pointer is related to, I use std::dynamic_pointer_cast(). The situation is as follows: just one std::dynamic_pointer_cast() is displayed, but I could have many depending on how many check I need to do to understand "who" is the pointer that I'm getting from the interface.
class Class1
{
public:
    Class1()
    {
    }
    
    void DoSomething()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<base_class> pointer_check(raw_ptr_from_interface);
        m_shared_ptr_1 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<derived_class_1>(pointer_check);
        if(m_shared_ptr_1)
        {
            // Do things with m_shared_ptr_1, for example access data, etc.
        }
    }
    
    ~Class1()
    {

    }
    
private:

    std:shared_ptr m_shared_ptr_1;
};

int main()
{
        Class1 class1();
        class1.DoSomething();
}

Suppose the main you see is the main of my app. In the example I provide here, I just instantiate Class1 and then call the DoSomething() function that I think contains the problem. So, as you can see, the pointer_check variable is initialized with the raw pointer raw_ptr_from_interface passed through the interface and then a std::dynamic_pointer_cast() is used to understand who the raw_pointer_from interface is among its possibily derived classes. Here everything works, the std::dynamic_pointer_cast(), I can enter the if(m_shared_ptr_1) when the passes pointer is effectively a pointer to derived_class_1.
However, it happens that when the app is terminated and the destructor of Class1 is invoked an exception is raised when trying to destroy the smart pointers.
What am I doing wrong?? I fear I'm not using correclty the smart pointers, but I really do not understand what I'm doing wrong and that's why I'm asking your help.

what does the classes 'base_class' and 'derived_class_1' look like? and the declaration of 'raw_ptr_from_interface' ?

Note that Class1 class1(); declares a function, which is likely not what you want.

well, we don't have any information about your raw_ptr_from_interface. Maybe whatever is giving you that pointer is ALSO freeing it?

One thing experience has taught me is that the place where you think the problem is, is probably not where the problem is. (And type-switching with dynamic casts is usually a sign that the design needs rethinking. )

Giving std::shared_ptr ownership of an object through a pointer that you got from "somewhere" is a mistake more often than not. Are you absolutely sure that nobody else wants the object it points to any more?

"an exception is raised": A C++ exception or a signal like SEGFAULT? As far as I am aware, std::default_delete can't throw, and neither can ~shared_ptr

For further assistance, show a [mcve]. In particular, it's important where the mysterious raw_ptr_from_interface comes from and what object (if any) it points to. Wrapping an arbitrary raw pointer into a shared_ptr is highly suspicious, it suggests your design may not have clear responsibilities for lifetime management.

Please complete you code to run on its own, see MRE.
